# prompt in window for vbscript

Tags: command-line, vbscript, wsh

I have a vbscript that runs on the command line in xp. It accepts one argument for the path to a directory.  Is there a simple way to prompt the user in the command line box for this?

If not, I can just echo what was passed in to show the user what they actually typed in case of typos.

Thanks,
James

Aftermath:

Here is the code I ended up with:
    On Error Resume Next
    strDirectory = InputBox(Message, Title, "For example - P:\Windows\")

```
If strDirectory = "" Then
    'Wscript.Echo cancelledText
Else
    'Wscript.Echo enteredText & strDirectory
etc...
```

I found some snippets and it turned out to be really simple to work with the inputBox.

HTH.
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WScript.StdIn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y8934a7%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property to read from the the standard input. If you want to supply the path when invoking the script, you can pass the path as a parameter. You'll find it in the [`WScript.Arguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the choice command, [choice](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php)
it sets errorlevel to the value selected. I think it comes with DOS, Windows 95,98, then MS dropped it and then came back again in Windows 7 and probably Vista

P.D. oh never mind, I read again and you're in XP. There are other options, like  `set /p name= What is your name?` would create a variable %name% you can use